# Material UI Half Star Rating not showing properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I hover over the stars, the half star is showing below the star

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code in codesandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the style being applied to that element. I had a half-star that was off to the right and fixed it by applying `text-align: 'left'`. Your issue is the half-star is below. If you post your code I can help troubleshoot which css property needs to be updated specifically.

Comment: Could you please have a look on this, for example? https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-robinson-kyfgk